# Connection string value is wrong

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I have many databases in my server which have the same two tables. The databases are named Hello1, Hello2 etc. They are created in runtime. I'm adding an .edmx item in my project for Hello1. I want to use the same .edmx file for the other databases because they all have the same tables (with different rows of course).

The connection string in my web.config file is this one:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyEntities.csdl|res://*/MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=10.10.10.10;Initial Catalog=Hello1;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In my C# code I want this:

```
MyEntities me = new MyEntities(theConnectionString);
```

theConnectionString will be the same as above, but instead Hello1 it will have the right database name. What should be the value of theConnectionString?

I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
"metadata=res://*/MyEntities.csdl|res://*/MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=10.10.10.10;Initial Catalog=Hello6;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
```

Comment: It _should_ work, I did it often. What kind of error you get? Are you sure that DB (hello6) exists and it's accessible?

Comment: @Adriano The error is "Keyword not supported 'data source'"

Comment: Did you mean to also change the Data source number as well as the initial catalog?

Comment: @KAJ No, the server remains the same. 10.10.10.10 remains the same

Comment: So why does it say 10.0.0.201 ?

Comment: @KAJ I changed it. Now see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `&quot;` with **single quotes**:

```
"metadata=res://*/MyEntities.csdl|res://*/MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=10.10.10.10;Initial Catalog=Hello6;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'"
```

Comment: @Srcee OK, I modified my answer with a different solution.

Comment: Keyword not supported 'data source'"

Comment: @Srcee OK, I think I got it now :)

Comment: Correct, but instead of EntityClient it should be SqlClient. Tnx :)